# How to schedule jenkins job to run with seconds unit?

Tags: jenkins, cron, batch-processing, hudson

Jenkins job trigger cron expression format is ? ? ? ? ?.
It cannot possible set the seconds unit.

But I want schedule seconds unit, like run at everyday 15:20:10.
Because there is a job with cron(0 12 * * *) and every minute job, and these two job must not to run simultaneously.

How can I do that?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have several options to do that :

1. use [lock plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Locks+and+Latches+plugin) to wait until your first job run will finish and only than trigger it.
2. use the **Quiet period** option in the Job configuration , add 10 seconds so the job will sleep 10 seconds after it trigger.

Comment: thanks for help. lock plugin is deprecated and [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) is altenative.

Comment: but i can't find how to set the throttle category.

Comment: did you check here - https://github.com/jenkinsci/throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin/blob/master/README.md ?

Comment: thanks my mistake, i found it in global configuration page.